# How to change the default location for Google Maps when "Location" preference is not available in Search Settings?

Tags: google-maps, location

This has already been asked: [How do I set a default Google Maps location?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57909/how-do-i-set-a-default-google-maps-location)

But I am in an unusual situation, same as [Neets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/63951/neets) as [in this comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/57909/how-do-i-set-a-default-google-maps-location#comment46699_57915). Every time I log into Google Maps (the new one, but I believe it was the same for the old one as well), it defaults to a view of the US. It was suggested in the previous post to update this via Search Settings, but there is no Location option there for me, as others have reported. Please see the following screenshot. I am signed into my personal Google account when I see this view:

[image: Location preference not available in Search Settings for Google Maps]

Can anyone solve this, or is it a glitch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What URL are you using to access Google Maps?

The default location would seem to be dependent on the Google Maps URL, or rather the "Top Level Domain" (TLD).

For example,

- If I go to `https://www.google.com/maps` I see the US.
- If I go to `.co.uk` I see the UK.
- If I go to `.co.id`, I see Indonesia.
- `.com.au` - Australia, etc.

Incidentally, if I visit `.com` (from the UK) I also don't see the "Location" setting. I only see this when I visit one of the ccTLDs (ie. `.co.uk`, `.co.id`, etc.).

Comment: Yup, you were 100% right - I was at the .com - thank you. Incidentally, not to be a pest, but if you did happen to see my final comment on your answer over in Webmasters on hreflang vs. geotargeting, I'd be incredibly grateful to hear your thoughts. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open googlemaps from the relevant TLD (e.g. .com for US, .co.uk for UK etc)
2. Sign in.
3. Set your home/work place
4. Place the area/zoom of the map as you want it to appear when you open googlemaps.
5. Save a bookmark when the screen looks as you want it.

Voila. Next time you click on the googlemaps bookmark, you get to a map zoomed & panned as you want it, with a place indicator on your home/work address!